# Custom tag in documents uploaded using API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the docusign API on my website to allow users to sign documents. For this I have used tags such as `[#<COMPANY>#]` in my document before uploading it, so that it is visible to end user in the form of docusign tags of signing, entering text data, etc.

There is a certain document where I require user to enter multiple text fields. these are different text fields and hence he will be entering different values in them. For this I use `[#<CUSTOMREQUIRED>#]` and `[#<CUSTOMTEXT>#]` tags in document. However, whatever value user enters in one field is duplicated in the others. How do i distinguish between the tags?

Answer (score 1):

If whatever value the user enters in one field is duplicated in the others, it's because the fields are "named" the same (i.e., have the same tab Label).  If you want DocuSign to treat them as entirely separate fields, make sure that **tabLabel** (in REST API) [or **TabLabel** in the SOAP API] is set to a distinct value for each field.