# Custom tabs with duplicate tab label name not getting filled in

Tags: tabs, docusignapi

According to: [Custom tag in documents uploaded using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867228/custom-tag-in-documents-uploaded-using-api/18875682#18875682), multiple tabs with the same tab label should all be getting filled in with the same value, however, for me, only the first instance is getting that value.  I have multiple text tabs with the same tab label, and am creating the envelope with: "text" + "tabLabel" + kvp.Key + "tabLabel" + "value" + kvp.Value + "value" + "text" , yet only the first occurrence of that tab label gets the value.  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your API request, try prefacing the **tabLabel** with **\\***.  For example, if multiple text tabs have the label "address", the portion of the API request to populate those tabs (each with the value '123 Main Street') would look like this:

```
"tabs":{
    "textTabs":[
       {
          "tabLabel":"\\*address",
          "value":"123 Main Street"
       },
    ],
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks.  I'm using the xml API, so I just added a single backslash and asterisk in front of each tablabel value.