# Custom tabs with duplicate tab label name not getting filled in in both locations

Tags: docusignapi

I wanted to follow up to the post below and note that I am having the same issue. When looking at the API log, it looks like the code is written correctly (per the article linked below), but it still isn't working. Below is an example of a tab that comes from the API log:

```
{"tabLabel":"\\*Investor State","value":"TX"}
```

[Custom tabs with duplicate tab label name not getting filled in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789380/custom-tabs-with-duplicate-tab-label-name-not-getting-filled-in)

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thank you!

(DocuSign supported asked me to post over here for help!)

Comment: Are you positive all the tabs you are trying to fill have the same `tabLabel` set?  Looking at your example they all must have their tab label set to "Investor State".  To help debug you should create then do a `GET` call on the recipients' tabs and make sure the tab labels are correctly set.

Comment: They do have the same label. I figured out what was wrong and posted it in the answer below. Thank you and Jenny for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging yesterday and last night, the issue appears to be occurring because the tab's `Initial Value` field was set with the tab label. By clearing the `Initial Value`, the API was able to populate all of the fields correctly. So, problem solved!

Interestingly, if you have something in the `Initial Value` field, the API will overwrite the initial value once, but not multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Are you updating an in-flight or draft envelope? So the envelope already has multiple tabs of the same name and you want to update one = update all of them? Just want to get more details to try and replicate what you are doing.

If not, the only thing I can think of is perhaps your tabs are spread over a few documents within the envelope and your account is set to populate tabs only within documents (the scope can be set to document or envelope) AND you only have one occurrence of that tab in the first document.

Comment: What I am doing is putting the custom tabs into the document, then having the API fill them. Then the Recipient will need to fill out a few things (that don't get passed through from our site via the API), but even before the Recipient completes any of the fields, the duplicate tabs are not grabbing the right data.

For example:

-1st instance of custom tab named "Address 1", pulled from the API which has a field called "Address 1"
<br>**Address 1:** 123 Fake Street
<br>
<br>-2nd instance of the Address 1 custom tab
<br>**Address 1:** Address 1 (in this case, the Address 1 is the default text)